# java ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor significantly exceeds the set time

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

**Simplified showcase**

```
public class SchedulerIssueShowcase {

    private static final int delay = 5000;
    private static final ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutorScheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(4);

    @UIThread
    public void schedule() {
        threadPoolExecutorScheduler.schedule(() -> Log.debug("Started after delay"), delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

}
```

It is java 14 desktop app. We have about 1% of customers who report delays in the execution start (the debug line as the first line in the execution appears already delayed) of the scheduled task up to minutes instead of 5s.
What would be the reason ? The only reason I can think of is overloaded host computer, that is valid option but somehow I am not really sure about it.

**Questions**

Can you think about more reasons ?
How would you debug it ?

Answer (score 1):

You have seriously misunderstood the nature of your 5 second argument. That is not a time-out. Just the opposite, that is a *delay*. Your submitted task waits five seconds before *starting* its work. Read [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Your code sets no limits on how long a task can take.

As for why some of your tasks take longer than others, obviously we cannot diagnose that without knowing your code base, your computer hardware and software, and your deployment scenario including network and database performance.

In some scenarios, concurrent tasks will see a tremendous improvement with the new [virtual threads](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8277131) provided by Project Loom. A work-in-progress, experimental builds of Project Loom technology are available now, built on early-access Java 18. See talks and interviews with Ron Pressler or Alan Bateman.

Comment: I am sorry I will need to rephrase my question, obviously I did not ask properly.

Answer (score 1):

You have created `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` with pool size 4 so it will only ever run maximum of 4 tasks at a time, even if there are more items that have exceeded their expected start delay. The remainder will have to wait for one of the executor threads to be available. You can demonstrate with this simple code which records number of active threads and counts the tasks per thread:

```
// import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
int delay = 5000;

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutorScheduler = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(4);
var threads = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,AtomicInteger>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    threadPoolExecutorScheduler.schedule(() -> {
       String tName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
       threads.computeIfAbsent(tName, tn -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
       System.out.println(tName+" Start threads#"+threads.size() + " = "+threads);
       try {Thread.sleep(20000); } catch(Exception lost) {}
       System.out.println(tName+" END");
       }
       , delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

It submits 10 tasks with 5 second delay, and you can see that max thread count is 4, and the last 6 tasks cannot start unless first 4 are completed.

```
pool-1-thread-2 Start threads#1 = {pool-1-thread-3=1, pool-1-thread-2=1, pool-1-thread-4=1}
pool-1-thread-4 Start threads#3 = {pool-1-thread-3=1, pool-1-thread-2=1, pool-1-thread-4=1}
pool-1-thread-3 Start threads#2 = {pool-1-thread-3=1, pool-1-thread-2=1, pool-1-thread-4=1}
pool-1-thread-1 Start threads#4 = {pool-1-thread-1=1, pool-1-thread-3=1, pool-1-thread-2=1, pool-1-thread-4=1}
pool-1-thread-2 END
pool-1-thread-2 Start threads#4 = {pool-1-thread-1=1, pool-1-thread-3=1, pool-1-thread-2=2, pool-1-thread-4=1}
pool-1-thread-3 END
pool-1-thread-3 Start threads#4 = {pool-1-thread-1=1, pool-1-thread-3=2, pool-1-thread-2=2, pool-1-thread-4=1}
pool-1-thread-4 END
pool-1-thread-4 Start threads#4 = {pool-1-thread-1=1, pool-1-thread-3=2, pool-1-thread-2=2, pool-1-thread-4=2}
pool-1-thread-1 END
pool-1-thread-1 Start threads#4 = {pool-1-thread-1=2, pool-1-thread-3=2, pool-1-thread-2=2, pool-1-thread-4=2}
pool-1-thread-2 END
pool-1-thread-2 Start threads#4 = {pool-1-thread-1=2, pool-1-thread-3=2, pool-1-thread-2=3, pool-1-thread-4=2}
pool-1-thread-3 END
pool-1-thread-3 Start threads#4 = {pool-1-thread-1=2, pool-1-thread-3=3, pool-1-thread-2=3, pool-1-thread-4=2}
pool-1-thread-4 END
pool-1-thread-1 END
pool-1-thread-2 END
pool-1-thread-3 END
```

You have reached a point where too many tasks are running at once - this is either a flaw in the tasks, or perhaps you need to consider a different thread / executor service strategy. As per @Basil Bourque answer project LOOM could make handling much easier.

Diagnose further / debug with a decent IDE like Eclipse, add logging statements (perhaps not log4j!), and use other information such as stack traces (`jstack <pid>` or CTRL-Break in console) to help you identify the code that is failing.